# Go back to "previous previous" Activity - finish() or startActivity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, activity-finish, start-activity

I have this folder-like structure of Activities, where one goes to the next one by `startActivity(..)`

> HomeActivity --> Folder 1 (GridView) --> Subfolder 1 (ListView) -->
>   item (WebView)

And there is no Subsubfolder.

On each of the Activities there are a BACK button and a HOME button. Let's say I got to "Subfolder 1" through Home and Folder 1 Activities

Now I want the HOME button on "Subfolder 1" (and also "item") to make the app go back to HomeActivity. I know it's "possible" by using `startActivity(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.java);`

But I thought normally this is not good because this makes a new Activity leaving the previous one unused, wasting the stack space (?), and is not what I really want to do. Moreover if there were input fields being edited on HomeActivity they'd be reset if I just started a new HomeActivity.

So my question is is there any better way to go *BACK* to a grandparent Activity directly from grandchild Activity (rather than calling grandparent as a child of grandchild) (sounds wrong already)

P.S. I tried with `finish()` , with this I could go from Folder 1 back to Home. And also `finish()`ing Folder 1 before calling Subfolder would bring me back to Home when I `finish()` Subfolder too, but the "back" button in Subfolder would not work then, so this doesn't work for me. And I use Eclipse to code if that matters.

Comment: Please take a look for intent flags like FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, there are many answers here in stackoverflow regarding these flags!

Comment: If finish() is working for you and you want the same functionality using back button, you can override onBackPressed() and call finish() in it.

Comment: thanks all, I never knew about these flag things.